# Can you be sure that all template types are correct when code compiles correctly?

Tags: c++

Since in C++, when you use templates, there is no code generated until instantiation. The compiler will only generate code for the instantiated types. Does this mean that when my code (that uses templates) compiles, I can be sure there are no type conflicts and my code won't crash at runtime due to type errors?

If not, can someone provide me with an example in which template code compiles successfully but still crashes at runtime?

Comment: If your code compile, you don't have compile error. You may still have runtime error as for any code though.

Comment: Types are a compile-time concept. They don't exist at runtime (RTTI notwithstanding).

Comment: @Angew: But a template instanciated *for* a type does exist at runtime, and if that template for that particular type gives a runtime error...

Comment: Can you elaborate what do you mean  by "type error(s)"?

Comment: @DevSolar I was basically after what "won't crash at runtime due to type errors" means. There are no "type errors" at runtime, since there are no types at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since template instantiations result in code being generated that depends on template parameters, all that is needed is for one of the template instantiations to result in code that yields a "crash".

Then it comes down to what you mean by a "crash".    If a "crash" includes an exception being thrown without being caught by the program (so `terminate()` is called), the following will compile but produce a crash

```
  #include <stdexcept>
  #include <vector>

  struct foo
  {
       foo() {throw std::runtime_error("crash");};
  };

  int main()
  {
       std::vector<double> d(2);     // okay, unless memory allocation fails
       std::vector<foo> f(2);     // will throw an exception
  }
```

If you mean that code can exhibit undefined behaviour (which means anything can occur, but one potential result is abnormal program termination) then change the constructor of `foo` in the above to exhibit undefined behaviour.   For example, dereference a NULL pointer, divide by zero, etc.   A "crash" is not guaranteed (such is the nature of undefined behaviour) but is a distinct possibility in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly your question but strictly related is the fact that you can have template instantiation successful for some types and failing for others.

For example here:

```
template <class T>
struct xyz_t
{
    std::string string_value(void) const{ return v; }
    T v;
};

void abc(void)
{
    xyz_t<std::string> a;
    xyz_t<int> b;

    a.string_value(); // compiles
    b.string_value(); // fails, because returns int for std::string
}
```

This is the problem that concepts are trying to solve: find out which constraint impose on template parameter in order to ensure successiful compilation.

Answer (score 1):

All C++ type rules are enforced by the compiler, at compile time. Obviously this happens only after all types are known, which means all templates are instantiated.

You may still have `dynamic_cast` checks return `nullptr` or throw at runtime, but that's by design: `dynamic_cast` is an RTTI mechanism and you can handle the failures. Also, this is unrelated to templates.